# "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf "rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, paperclip

Im getting a an error in my nginx error log.  Im trying to add increase file size by adding a folder called .ebextensions and adding a file called 01_files.config. something to do with the http {} im not really sure how to update this file to make it work!! thanks!!

**In my 01_files.config**

```yaml
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        http {
          client_max_body_size 20M;
        }

        service nginx reload
```

**image.config** "located in the .ebextensions folder"

```yaml
packages:
  yum:
    ImageMagick-devel: []
```

### /var/log/nginx/error.log

`2016/06/05 03:23:01 [emerg] 6587#0: "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:1`

**/var/log/nginx/error.log-20160605**

`[error] 2818#0: *19636 client intended to send too large body: 2771652 bytes, client: 172.31.24.171, server: _, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", host:`

Comment: Can you post the error you get ?

Comment: Hey!! Updated error log and another one of my files in .ebextensions folder!!

Comment: The error means that you can't put that http {} section into the files section. which means the client_max_body_size is ignored.

Comment: so if i just remove the http and keep max body size and service nginx reload then It will work?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know nginx enough to tell you that. I assume no. You probably have an http section in your nginx.conf somewhere, see if it works if you put the body_size in there.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you remove the surrounding http and reload directives, like so:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        client_max_body_size 20M;
```